# Traversing a complex DOM and scraping values

Tags: javascript, dom, web-scraping, puppeteer, innerhtml

Consider the following structure in **DOM.**

```
 <div class="bodyCells">
       <div style="foo">
           <div style="foo">
                <div style="foo"> 
                  <div style="foo1"> '1-contains the list of text elements I want to scrape'</div>
                  <div style="foo2"> '2-contains the list of text elements I want to scrape'</div>
                </div>
                <div style="foo"> 
                  <div style="foo3"> '3-contains the list of text elements I want to scrape'</div>
                  <div style="foo4"> '4-contains the list of text elements I want to scrape'</div>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

By using class name **bodyCells**, I need to scrape out the data from **each of the divs one at a time** (i.e) Initially from 1st div, then from the next div and so on and store it in separate arrays. How can I possibly achieve this? **(using puppeteer)**

**NOTE:** I have tried using class name directly to achieve this but, it gives **all the texts in a single array.** I need to **get data from each tag separately and store it in different arrays.**

***Expected Output:***

```
  array1=["text present within style="foo1" div tag"] 
  array2=["text present within style="foo2" div tag"] 
  array3=["text present within style="foo3" div tag"]
  array4=["text present within style="foo4" div tag"]
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
 var value=[];
value = await page1.evaluate(() =>{
if (!window.document){window.document = {};}
var textitems=[]
var extracted_items=[]
textitems = document.getElementsByClassName("bodyCells");
for (var i = 0; i < textitems.length; i++) {
  item=textitems[i].textContent
  extracted_items.push(item);
}
  return extracted_items;
});
```

Comment: for (const div of textitems[0].querySelectorAll("div")) { console.log(div); }

Comment: I need to store values of each div in separate arrays. How do I do that? @gillall

Comment: Try this inside loop: if (/[0-9a-zA-Z]/.test(div.childNodes[0].data)) result.push([div.childNodes[0].data]). But this is suitable only for your data. You must use ids, classes and tags if want scraping easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need...

```js
const html = `
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
      <div class="bodyCells">
        <div style="foo">
          <div style="foo">
            <div style="foo">
              <div style="foo1"> '1-contains the list of text elements I want to scrape'</div>
              <div style="foo2"> '2-contains the list of text elements I want to scrape'</div>
            </div>
            <div style="foo">
              <div style="foo3"> '3-contains the list of text elements I want to scrape'</div>
              <div style="foo4"> '4-contains the list of text elements I want to scrape'</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>`;

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

    const data = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll('div.bodyCells > div > div > div > div'),
      div => [div.innerText],
    ));

    console.log(data);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Output:

```
[
  [ "'1-contains the list of text elements I want to scrape'" ],
  [ "'2-contains the list of text elements I want to scrape'" ],
  [ "'3-contains the list of text elements I want to scrape'" ],
  [ "'4-contains the list of text elements I want to scrape'" ]
]
```